# Dojo related page is not opening properly in browser

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am new to DOJO. Whenever I am trying to load a page I am getting following errors. Can anyone solve it ??
Thanks in advance. :-)

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://www.ibm.com/webmaster/dbip/ip/?callback=dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript1._jsonpCallback"
>
> Error: declare: mixin #0 is not a callable constructor

Comment: could you post your code , we cant help without it

Comment: It's Showing HTTP Status 404 - /abc/webdev-modeselector-common.js

Comment: have you configured /abc location on your dojoConfig ,? could you post your project tree and config code ?

Comment: My Config code is this :-  var dojoConfig = {
 packages:[{
  name:"dojo",
  location:"../../../dojo"
 },{
  name:"dijit",
  location:"../../../dijig"
 }]
};